# How to fix an empty button for accessibility?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, wave, web-chat

I'm building a chat UI using React and it needs to be accessible. I am using the [Wolox/react-chat-widget](https://github.com/Wolox/react-chat-widget). I do not want to use the badge function. When testing it using the WAVE tool, `tt` triggers an empty button error for the web chat launcher button. What is a work around for fixing this issue without modifying the base library?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to fix this without either extending or editing the source.

The error is caused because the button to launch chat has no readable content, only an SVG file.

You could easily fix this (albeit not an ideal fix but the minimum effort way of doing it) by modifying [components/Widget/components/Launcher/index.js](https://github.com/Wolox/react-chat-widget/blob/master/src/components/Widget/components/Launcher/index.js) to simply add information to the alt tag that is currently empty in the open and close image. (`alt="close chat", alt="open chat"`).

Better yet send a pull request asking the author to update it so everyone benefits from the added accessibility.

Bear in mind that there are loads of other accessibility issues to consider with this chat such as managing the focus within the modal, escape key to close etc. (it may have these but you have to think about them.)